# Estimating the correlation length on a periodic lattice

Tags: computational-physics, correlation-functions, spin-models

I am trying to estimate the distance dependent correlation length of on a 2D lattice. Usually if $C(r)$ is the correlation function, I can estimate it as:

$$\frac{1}{\xi(r)} = - \ln\{C(r+1) / C(r)\} $$

But due to periodic boundary conditions, the correlation function is like a hyperbolic cosine instead of a decaying exponential. For a lattice of size $L$, I can write the ansatz for the correlation function as:

$$ C(r) = A\left[\exp\left(-\frac{r}{\xi}\right) + \exp\left(-\frac{L-r}{\xi}\right)\right] = 2A\exp\left(-\frac{L}{2\xi}\right) \cosh\left(\frac{L/2 - r}{\xi}\right)$$

Now on taking the ratio I have (using some identities of $\cosh$):

$$\frac{C(r+1)}{C(r)} = \cosh(1/\xi) - \tanh\left(\frac{L/2 - r}{\xi}\right)\sinh(1/\xi)$$

I am not sure how to use this to calculate the value of $\xi$ as the ratio is always less than 1 so I can't simple take $\cosh^{-1}$ on this for values of $r$ close to $L/2$. Am I doing something wrong here? If there is a better way to deal with this then please let me know as well. Thanks!